# Updating the amount of widgets on a screen when you open it?

Tags: python, kivy, peewee

I have a Screen that holds a ScrollView that holds a StackLayout of buttons. I can generate as many buttons as I have rows in my database table, but only when the app is first loaded. I have a button that can add rows to my table, but no more buttons are added to the screen unless the app is fully closed and reopened.

```
<InventoryScreen>:
    on_pre_enter: root.updateInv(self)
    name: "inventory" 
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Label:
            text: "Inventory"
            size_hint: 1, .25
        ScrollInventory:
        Button:
            text: "Back"
            size_hint: 1, None
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "Options"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "right"

<ScrollInventory@ScrollView>:
    InventoryStack: 
        size_hint: 1, None
        height: self.minimum_height     

<InventoryStack>:
    orientation: "lr-tb"
    padding: ("20dp", "20dp")
    spacing: "20dp", "20dp"
```

```
class InventoryStack(StackLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        for i in Inventory.select():
            size = dp(100)
            dictItem = model_to_dict(i) 
            print(dictItem['name'])
            invButton = Button(text=dictItem['name'], size_hint=(None, None), size=(size, size))
------------self.add_widget(invButton)
        print("-" * 35)

    def viewInventory(self):
        for i in Inventory.select():
            size = dp(100)
            dictItem = model_to_dict(i) 
            print(dictItem['name'])
            invButton = Button(text=dictItem['name'], size_hint=(None, None), size=(size, size))
------------self.add_widget(invButton)
        print("-" * 35)
        
class InventoryScreen(Screen):
    def updateInv(self, *largs):
        InventoryStack().viewInventory()
```

I've minimized this code as much as possible to identify the problem. It works exactly how I want it to EXCEPT for the self.add_widget(invButton) lines. Just not sure where to look in the kivy docs to find a solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your line of code:

```
InventoryStack().viewInventory()
```

is creating a new instance of `InventoryStack`, and calling `viewInventory()` on that new instance. That new instance is not the instance that appears in your GUI, so it has no visible effect. You need a reference to the `InventoryStack` that is actually in your GUI.

One way to solve this is to create a class variable that contains a reference to the correct instance. Something like this:

```
class InventoryStack(StackLayout):
    instance = None  # class variable to hole reference to the instance

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        InventoryStack.instance = self
        .
        .
        .
```

Then use that reference in the `updateInv()` method:

```
class InventoryScreen(Screen):
    def updateInv(self, *largs):
        InventoryStack.instance.viewInventory()
```

This is the beginnings of a `Singleton`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74727374/singleton-pattern-python).